# Derivative of matrix exponential -- general formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Suppose there's square matrix $\hat{A}$, whose entrances are differentiable functions $f_{ij}(x_1, x_2,..., x_n)$. With $\mu = 1, ..., n$. I want to calculate such formula

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}} \exp{(A)}$$

Using series expansion for matrix exponential I derived following relation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}} \exp{(A)} = \exp(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}} A) - \hat{1}$$,

where $\hat{1}$ is $n \times n$ square identity matrix. Since I haven't seen this formula in any textbook or script I just wanted to ask if it's true for any matrix exponential.

Comment: Why $f_{ij}$ and not $a_{ij}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it doesn't matter. The fact they are differentiable functions does.

Comment: Good notation does matter. You're introducing new symbols carelessly.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo for me naming the function by $f$ is more intuitive than $a$. Nevermind.

Comment: Have you tried the case where the matrix is $1 \times 1$?

Comment: For series expansion it works as well, doesn't it?

Comment: NO! you blew it. [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map).